# What's the relation between Juju project and Ubuntu/Canonical?

Tags: juju, canonical

Juju: [www.juju.ubuntu.com](http://www.juju.ubuntu.com)

Who is the owner of Juju, Canonical?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Canonical is the owner.

**From Wikipedia**:

*Juju (formerly Ensemble) is an open source service orchestration management tool developed by Canonical Ltd., the company behind Ubuntu. Juju allows software to be quickly deployed, integrated and scaled on a wide choice of cloud services or servers.*

**From Canonical.com**:

*Juju is the Ubuntu project’s service orchestration tool, 
    which simplifies the installation and management of cloud applications.*

See here for references:

[Canonical projects list](https://www.canonical.com/projects)

[Wikipedia article on Juju](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juju_%28software%29)

Comment: To add on: Juju is a cloud orchestration tool by Canonical, which is open source and not limited to orchestration of Ubuntu machines (also can do Windows and soon CentOS)